# How to see what options my php was configured with?

Tags: php, compilation, settings, configure

I have a production server that is currently running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4, and [it has a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38255659/4233593). I found [a patch](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=186ffcb72c982b0235761bdd6388ff1c36d79568) and I would like to verify it by building the same PHP version *and options/extensions* from source with the patch applied.

I have cloned the repository from http://git.php.net/, checked out tag `php-5.5.9`, created a new branch, applied the patch, installed all the build dependencies, and created the `configure` script with `buildconf`

Now I want to build it configured with all the same options and extensions that are present on my production server. At the very least, I know that I am going to need to run:

```
./configure --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC
```

But how do I detect all the other options that were configured when PHP was built on my production server?

Comment: phpinfo() contains the compile command line somewhere in all of the output.

Comment: As @MarcB said, you can use `phpinfo()`. You can also use `php -i`, given that you have access to the command line.

Comment: @EdCottrell I do have access to the CLI, and looking at both I can see that the information is probably there, but no straight forward translation of the specific compile flags I need.

Comment: @MarcB there is definitely no *"compile command line"* in my `phpinfo()` output. Is this something that's possibly only available in later versions of PHP?

Comment: or maybe it was only in older php's. the version I've got now doesn't include it either. it's been a looong time since I had to dig through phpinfo output. either it's optional, or was removed in newer versions.

Comment: @MarcB so I went ahead and plowed through with options I knew I needed, still unsure as to whether I got everything, but when I run `phpinfo()` with my custom build I *do in fact* see a `Configure Command` table cell with the exact flags I passed when building. Not sure why this isn't present in `PHP 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4` but it appears there when custom building `PHP-5.5.9` How mysterious is that?

Comment: guess it could be a diff between `php -i` and `phpinfo()`. I only checked cli here.

Comment: @MarcB yes, using `php -i` also shows the `Configure Command` on custom build only, but I still have no idea how to get it from the Ubuntu distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
php -i | grep configure
```