# Data too long for column 'users' at row 1

Tags: mysql, symfony

I'm working with Symfony2 and Mysql 8 . while working on localhost `wamp` it workds perfectly but when working on a distant server using a server `IIS` the problem accure.

While trying to insert in mysql database, i'm getting the following error

```
  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (name,familyName) values (?,?) with 
  params["\xe9","name"]:
  SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'name' at row 1
```

The problem is that i'm inserting a special charachter `é` . i'm setting my table as UTF8_mb4. 
and all characters get excepted expect `é`

Comment: can you check if below answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/38255659/2750541

Comment: SET NAMES utf8?

Comment: yes already done

Comment: `INSERT INTO users (name,familyName)` and yet the error message says "Data too long for **column** 'users'". That's odd.

Comment: @fancyPants it's for column name , error in typing

Comment: The problem is not in mysql, but in the server IIS , it doesn't encode my params as UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to the problem , it resides in the IIS, it reads my data as ASCII not UTF.
Fixed with the command :

```
   reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\w3svc\Parameters /v 
   FastCGIUtf8ServerVariables /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d REQUEST_URI\0PATH_INFO
```